# How to use " WITH " clause in MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a Mysql query . I am getting some error on WITH clause of select function .

This is the sample query :

```
CREATE TRIGGER  SAMPLE BEFORE INSERT ON SERVER
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(S.ID) FROM SERVER S WITH UR) >= (SELECT L.SERVERS FROM SAMPLE L WHERE L.ID = 1 LIMIT 1)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '73550' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='+ID';
    END IF;
  END;
```

and i am getting the error :

```
right syntax to use near 'UR) >= (SELECT L.SERVERS FROM SAMPLE L WHERE L.ID = 1 LIMIT 1))
```

Is WITH clause doesn't support in Mysql ?  Or any other syntax should i use ? Any suggestion would helpful .

**update :**

Also i am using another query :

```
CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_TRIGGER NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      SET NEW.RID = (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_2 WHERE ACTIVE=0 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY WITH RS USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS);
      IF (NEW.RID IS NULL) THEN
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '73550' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='+ID';
      END IF;
  END;
```

getting another error

```
right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1 WITH RS USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS);
      IF (NEW.RID IS NULL) THEN'
```

Comment: "WITH UR" is DB2.  Try "WITH NOLOCK" for MySql

Comment: I have updated my question with another issue for `WITH RS` . please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

In DB2, `with ur` means "with uncommitted read".  This is a locking mechanism in the database, as explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_isolationclause.html).

If you are porting code to MySQL, I would not worry about this.  So, just remove it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER  SAMPLE BEFORE INSERT ON SERVER
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(S.ID) FROM SERVER S) >= (SELECT L.SERVERS FROM SAMPLE L WHERE L.ID = 1 LIMIT 1)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '73550' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='+ID';
    END IF;
  END;
```

Comment: Thanks . I have updated my question with another issue for `WITH RS` . please suggest any solution for that too? that is also related to locking mechanism

Comment: Should i remove `WITH RS USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS` in second updated query ??

Comment: give that a try.  "WITH RS AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS" is also a DB2 thing.

Comment: But i have tried to remove `WITH RS USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS` and getting error 
Unknown column 'RID' in 'NEW'

Comment: I have updated the entire query and i removed NO CASCADE  from that query  and added LIMIT 1 for FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY . still getting same error . I am trying to run in online http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler

Comment: @user2986042 . . .This answers the question that you originally asked.  If you have another question, then ask it as *another* question.  It is rude to change a question after it has been answered, because that can draw downvotes to the answer.